# loadbalancer pricing in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

Could you help me with understanding the pricing for loadbalancer in Azure. Here what I've found in manual https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/load-balancer/
Am I right, if I add several Frontend IP configurations, Backend pools and Inbound NAT rules only, without  any Load balancing rules I'll be charged only for the amount of data processed? The reason I am asking is that I can't find what is "outbound rules" there is no such item in the settings. 
And,in general, my aim is just to redirect ports from public IP to VM.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a single VM?

Comment: Yes, I've already deployed one

Comment: If you have one and only one VM, then you do not need a load balancer, you could just give the VM a public IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If you are creating only Inbound NAT rules, you will be charged only for the amount of data processed and the charge of the Public IP address resource which is attached to the LB.

Outbound rules are not visible in Portal. You can configure it via CLI or PowerShell. It is used in scenarios where you have VMs without Public IP which are part of Internal Load balancers and need to talk to Internet.